# Android firebase: child is being overwritten when I update it

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database structure like this:

```
       post
       |
       user1
       |
       user2
       |
       |-------title:"new title"
       |-------body: "new post" 
       |-------votes: 
                    |randomid:"value"
```

So as you can see I have a path called `post/ user1/ user2`, under this path I save a map (key/value) consisting of 3 children:

title: with value of string.

body: with value of string.

votes: with value of a map.

**problem**

The thing here is that I save the votes as (random ids) under `votes`, so I want to update the votes each time a button is clicked with new push id on each button click.

But the problem is that in my case the `votes` value is being overwritten instead of pushed.

**what I tried**

```
//on vote button click

//generate a push id

DatabaseReference push = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push();

String push_id = push.getkey();

//votes map

Map votes_map = new HashMap();
votes_map.put(push_id , "value");

//post map

Map post_map = new HashMap();
post_map.put("title","new title");
post_map.put("body", "new post");
post_map.put("votes", votes_map); 

//path

Map path = new HashMap();
path.put("post/user1/user2", post_map);  

//update
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


root.updateChildren(path);
```

**I EXPECTED**

That if I click vote 3 times I should have this at `votes`:

```
            -----votes:
                      |random_id: "value"
                      |random_id: "value"
                      |random_id: "value"
```

**I GOT**

this instead after clicking votes 3 times:

```
            -----votes:
                    |random_id: "value"
```

How to solve this to achieve the **I EXPECTED** case?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should write directly to the newly created vote. Something like this: `path.put("post/user1/user2/push_id", "value");`

Comment: @AndréKool the question is not about pushing the post, the question I am asking is how to push the child (votes).

Comment: Woops i made a mistake It should be something like this: `path.put("post/user1/user2/votes/push_id", "value");` Basicly instead of writing the entire votes_map you write a single vote.

Comment: @AndréKool I understand what you said (and you are right), but how can I do it according to my approach. I mean how to push the vote each time the whole path is updated.

Comment: This is starting to sound like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/388562) . What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @AndréKool as you can see above when I update the path `post/user1/user2`. The value of the field `votes` is being overwritten. My question is how to push it during this update.